# What is the best way to set all cells in a table to the same value?

Tags: powerquery, m

What is the best way to pass all cells in a table the same value?

For instance, if I start with this table:

[image]

How might I most easily change it to this:

[image]

Or to this:

[image]

I would like the solution to work for any size table, without having to hard-code the columns' names. So I'm pretty sure the solution will include Table.ColumnNames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a new table with the dimensions and table type of the original table. The table type includes column names and column data types (and any keys if these would be present).

**Note:** this won't work if the original table has a primary key, e.g. after removing duplicates.

```
let
    NewValue = "a",
    Source = Table1,
    NewTable = Table.FromColumns(List.Repeat({List.Repeat({NewValue},Table.RowCount(Source))},Table.ColumnCount(Source)), Value.Type(Source))
in
    NewTable
```